# Actual zoom option in Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, zooming

The in-built pdf viewer in Overleaf has functionalities for zoom in /out.

However, it does not provide the zoom level as a percentage (for example 100% like this)

Actually, I want to always view the content with actual size (100%) which will be very useful for me in adding graphics etc..

Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Comment: Probably a better question for overleaf support

Comment: Hi there, Tom from Overleaf Support here. We indeed do not have that. When you need to check how the document looks in proper size, we recommend downloading the PDF and viewing it locally. You may also try switching to the native PDF viewer in the project's menu, but on browsers I could try, the browser's native PDF viewer doesn't show the percents either. I have shared your message with our Product team for consideration.

Comment: @yo' Thank you for your reply. Actually I tried with the native pdf reader as well, and faced the same issue you have mentioned. Better to include that feature in an upcoming release. thank you.